# How to add host to ansible group when the host is running a certain role?

Tags: ansible

Imagine, you have a role that adds a NFSv4 mount point with Kerberos authentication.
This rule directly depends on the host being in the [ansible-freeipa/ipaclient](https://github.com/freeipa/ansible-freeipa/tree/master/roles/ipaclient) group s.t. the host can request Kerberos tickets.

Is there a way to automatically make all hosts that execute this role also member in the `ipaclient` group?

Or do you know a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"Automatically make all hosts that execute this role a member of the `ipaclient` group."*

A: Put this task into the role

```
- add_host:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    groups: ipaclient
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
```

Notes:

- Module [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html#notes) 
  *"only runs once for all the hosts in the play"*
- Make the changes permanent in [INI](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html#ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files)-style hosts file

```
- ini_file:
    allow_no_value: true
    path: "{{ path_to_hosts_file }}"
    section: ipaclient
    option: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

- Optionally, depending on the use-case, use [ansible_play_hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)